# breaks without scale_y_continuous() in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I was searching for a method to set breaks in a plot without using the scale_y_...(breaks=c(x1,x2)) function. The problem is the following: I want some boxplots.

```
    require(ggplot2)
    a <- rnorm(10, 0, 5)
    a <- as.data.frame(a); colnames(a) <- "test"

    ### original boxplot
    ggplot(data=a, mapping=aes(y=test, x=rep(1,10))) +
      geom_boxplot()

    ### scale_y_continous() cuts of my data points and changes the boxplot!
    ggplot(data=a, mapping=aes(y=test, x=rep(1,10))) +
      geom_boxplot() +
      scale_y_continuous(limits=c(-1,1), breaks=c(-1,0,1))

    ### I am therefore using coord_cartesian() but I am missing a breaks() function
    ggplot(data=a, mapping=aes(y=test, x=rep(1,10))) +
      geom_boxplot() +
      coord_cartesian(ylim = c(-1,1)) # +
    # breaks(c(-1,0,1))   # something like this
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Just curious, why would you want to zoom in on a boxplot?

Comment: It's not so much about zooming in but keeping the ylim constant for several boxplots that are plotted side by side.

Comment: In that case, it is better to use `log-scale` (or) `facet` with `scales="free"`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can combine `coord_cartesian()` and `scale_y_continuous()` in one plot, just remove `limits=c(-1,1)` from scale function. When you use `limits=` inside the scale function, data are subsetted in that diapason. `coord_cartesian()` just zooms that region of values.

```
 ggplot(data=a, mapping=aes(y=test, x=rep(1,10))) +
      geom_boxplot() +
      coord_cartesian(ylim = c(-1,1))+
      scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(-1,0,1))
```

Comment: Ah! Thank you for this!
I was trying to do that in combination with

ylim(c(,)) +
scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(,))

But then got the error message:
Scale for 'y' is already present. Adding another scale for 'y', which will replace the existing scale.

Your version works fine!

Comment: What if you want to not use `scale_y_continuous()` at all because you want your function to handle both continuous and discrete input? That is, sometimes you want to make the boxes horizontal with y discrete and x continuous, and sometimes you want the boxes vertical with x discrete and y continuous. Is there something like `ybreaks()`?